# How to create Thumbnail Provider (for windows explorer) using C#?

Tags: c#, thumbnails, explorer

In Windows 7 SDK there is example of Thumbnail Provider written on C++. 
Is it possible to write Thumbnail Provider using C#? 
Any examples?